# Как можно вывести максимальное/ последнее значение в таблице(через redbeanPHP)

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Искал на форуме решения, подобного не нашёл, грусть, печаль. Но надо только через redbeanPHP написать запрос который вывел максимальное значение date("U") из базы, или же найти последнее ( тк сортировка одинаковая будет). Не предлагайте тупо SQL решение, да..я видел, но надо именно на этой библиотеке.

Comment: пробовали сделать это самостоятельно?

Comment: Конечно но проблема в том, что в инструкциях нет таких параметров как max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте через `LIMIT`:

```
$last = R::findAll('table',' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1 ');
```

Или возможно подойдет `findLast`:

```
$last = R::findLast('table');
```

Comment: а findLast можно задать 2 условия? тип последняя запись для этого id? просто там есть необходимость вывести последнее сообщение конкретного пользователя, а не вообще последнее

Comment: попробуйте так `R::findLast('table', ' user_id = ? ',[$id]);`

Comment: спасибо огромное